# Is there an upper limit on the number of running ROS nodes?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working on a multi-agent simulation with ROS. Each agent will be composed of several nodes.
If let's say I build a basic agent with 4 nodes, and I want to run a simulation with 10 agents, I will have 40 nodes in total. However, I am not sure how to determine the scale-ability of this approach. Is there some upper limit on node number? What factors influence it?

Thank you for your time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235851/is-there-an-upper-limit-on-the-number-of-running-ros-nodes?/) by [highWaters](https://answers.ros.org/users/25790/highwaters/) on ROS Answers with karma: 176 on 2016-06-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-06-16**:
Closing this as the question has been answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The only limit to the number of nodes you can run is based on the system running them. You can run as many as your processor can handle, but if you run too many it will lag or possibly crash. You can't get a real number as some nodes are simplistic while others are incredibly complex.

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2016-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [highWaters](https://answers.ros.org/users/25790/highwaters/) on 2016-06-02**:
I see. I suppose I could also use threads inside nodes, in order to control the number of nodes.
Also, I found this question that relates to the topic; just posting it here for others, http://answers.ros.org/question/96921/design-question-where-does-the-business-logic-go/